# How to show content of Activity in full screen without flicker

Tags: android

how to make activity full screen and navigate back to previous activity without any UI flicker.

Answer (score 0):

full screen activity

use Theme

`<activity android:name"MainActivity" 
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">`

and `navigate back to previous activity without any UI flicker`
is mean how to make back button?

Comment: I mean if I navigate to any other non full Activity (by pressing back or open new Activity) I see status bar pushes new Activity down. Transition is not smooth.

Answer (score 0):

You can choose between two options

1. Apply new exit animation of Activity, such as fade out, scale out, .... It will reduce the lagging-effect to the eyes.
2. Use Fragment instead. Fragment transition is smoother than activity transition.

Try both ways and compare them to get the better options. I recommend you the second :D